# How to create dependent exposed filters in a view

Tags: views

I have three drop-down boxes just like ex:

```
1. class list (ClassI, ClassII...)
2. subject list (Hindi, English...)
3. chapter list (H-ChapterI, H-ChapterII, E-ChapterI, E-ChapterII...)
```

When a user clicks on class list drop-down, there will be two option (ClassI, ClassII and so on...). When I select ClassI in a subject list (Hindi, English and so on...) will become as same. When I select on Hindi in chapter list related to Hindi (HChapterI, HChapterII) all chapter will come. This is what I want in my view filter.

Comment: What Drupal version? Please tag your question with a Drupal version.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [Simple Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs), this also works with views and exposed filters out of the box.

Comment: I have tried to use it but it helps only on content level.How can i use it as exposed filter to visitors.

Comment: Views (exposed filter)
add a new filter using the field set-up as "Simple hierarchical select" or use "Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth; Simple hierarchical select)" as a new filter
use "Simple hierarchical select" as selection type
select "Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it"